# Kotlin Native how to convert ByteArray to String?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlin-native

I was playing with the [kotlin-native samples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/socket/src/main/kotlin/EchoServer.kt#L57).
I wonder how I could get `String` from `pinned` ByteArray. Just want to print it in the console.

Comment: What is the encoding that was used to convert chars to bytes in that array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## It seems that this API has changed

Now just use this: `string.toUtf8(start, end)`

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/commit/cba7319e982ed9ba2dceb517a481cb54ed1b9352#diff-45a5f8d37067266e27b76d1b68f01173

## Legacy version:

Use `stringFromUtf8`

```
/**
 * Converts an UTF-8 array into a [String]. Replaces invalid input sequences with a default character.
 */
fun ByteArray.stringFromUtf8(start: Int = 0, size: Int = this.size) : String =
        stringFromUtf8Impl(start, size)
```

See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/text/StringBuilder.kt).

And if the byteArray is like `CPointer<ByteVar>` by interoperating C APIs, pleace use `.toKString()` in Kotlin-Native

Comment: Thanks to @Willi Mentzel for adding the reference for`stringFromUtf8`'s source code.

Comment: Very thanks. But I can't find the source of `stringFromUtf8` in the referenced link ([here: StringBuilder.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/text/StringBuilder.kt)).

Comment: This API has been deprecated......ReplaceWith("string.toUtf8(start, end)" 
 https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/commit/cba7319e982ed9ba2dceb517a481cb54ed1b9352#diff-45a5f8d37067266e27b76d1b68f01173

Comment: The question was about converting ByteArray to String? 
How string.toUtf8(start, end) could help me?

Answer (score 32):

If you need a solution for the JVM, since `stringFromUtf8` is only available for the native platform, use [toString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-string.html) with a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) as argument:

```
val byteArray = "Hello World".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)   
val str = byteArray.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
```

If you specifically only want to target native, use [Sin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468361/1788806).

Comment: This answer is for JVM and it is at the very top even though the question was about Kotlin/Native.

Comment: @xdevs23 it’s a glitch in the matrix

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked:

1. `ByteArray.decodeToString()`
2. `ByteArray.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)`
3. `ByteArray.commonToUtf8String()`

They all gave the same result.

Answer (score -1):

The [OKIO](https://square.github.io/okio/) library has a helper method for this [commonToUtf8String](https://github.com/square/okio/blob/917ef3d78e50693bf7b138de0823cca4efa9e1af/okio/src/commonMain/kotlin/okio/internal/-Utf8.kt)

One can simply copy the method code don't need to add the entire lib just for this.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that could be used everyone but especially makes sense looking for a **Kotlin Multiplatform** solution and using `ktor` library already is using `io.ktor.utils.io.core.String` function directly without adding extra third pary library or extra actual class implementation. For example:

Your `build.gradle.kts` for all platforms:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:${Versions.ktor}")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:${Versions.ktor}")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-apache:${Versions.ktor}")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:${Versions.ktor}")
```

Then use it

```
io.ktor.utils.io.core.String(byteArray, offset, length, Charsets.UTF_8)
```