# How to convert byte array to image [kotlin]

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap

I want to convert byte array to image and show it in image view, but not sure how to do it. Can someone guide me please

I use this function to convert bitmap to byte array

```
private fun BitmapToByteArray(): ByteArray
    {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        btm1!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        val bitmapdata: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
        return bitmapdata
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
 fun byteArrayToBitmap(data: ByteArray): Bitmap {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size)
}
```

Comment: val x = final_str?.toByteArray()

byteArrayToBitmap(x)

fun byteArrayToBitmap(x: ByteArray): Bitmap {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(x, 0, x.size)
    }

is this correct ?

Comment: final_str is a ByteArrayOutputStream ?

Comment: final_str is the string that convert from byte array. so I turn it back into byte array.

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616075/7085389) how to convert String to byteArray

Comment: that's helped you ?

Comment: I got random symbol, instead of the object ID

Comment: you convert the ID to byte or the Image to String sorry I didn't understand what this ID is

Comment: sorry, I mean, if I covert bitmap like this bitmapdata.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()), I got random symbol after print it out in text view.

Comment: you add the image data in textView?

Comment: to convert an array of byte to String you must specify an Encoding like UTF 8 or what you want and when you come back to the byte array you must use the same encoding to avoid data losing

Comment: because the image gonna encrypt with secret text, so I am testing it with text view, but I got random symbol

Answer (score 1):

These extension functions are working

```
fun Bitmap.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
  val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
  this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
  return stream.toByteArray()
}

fun ByteArray.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
  return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this, 0, this.size)
}
```